Move data to another table based on array value
I have two Excel tables:
Table Process:

Table Orders:

When there is a Tag with the value of ProcessID, I would like to populate the column OrderID in table Process with OrderIDs from table Orders.
I was looking into Excel arrays, so if needed, I know how to change the Tags to something like {217,218,229,230}.
This is the result I'm looking for:


MY OWN SOLUTION:
After encoutering issues with solution proposed in answers below - for larger field sizes (Tags), I thought I found another solution which I posted here, but I'm deleting it now as that didn't work properly as I later figured it out.
I ended up adding the first and last bracket to the Tags string and then I brought my data to Access where I was able to easily achieve what I wanted with a simple SQL query:
UPDATE Processes, Orders
SET Processes.OrderID = [Orders].[ID]
WHERE (([Orders].[Tags] Like "*|" & [Processes].[ID] & "|*"));


You can do this with a formula:
=IFERROR(INDEX(OrderTab!A:A,MATCH("*|"&A2&"|*","|"&OrderTab!B:B&"|",0)),"Not Found")

Assuming your Order table is on a worksheet called OrderTab. Change this.
Result:


Upvoted, indeed shorter array formula.

First off I was receiving a "There's a problem with the formula", but I solved that by replacing all your commas (,) with semicolons (;). I think that's the right setting for my language. But I'm now getting "Not found" in all the fields. :/

I added a screenshot to my initial post

It works as well! I didn't use CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER as suggested in the post from Foxfire, so thank you both :)

While this does deal with the ranges as arrays, it's not an array formula. I'm glad you've got it going.

There seems to be a problem dealing with large number of Tags in table orders. If the nubmer of tags is about 50 or higher this function does not work any more. If I break up the Tags in 2 lines both keeping the same ID value, then it works fine again. Any advice on how to automate this? I have about 1500 lines on the Orders table. Would it be best to post a new question for this?

There seems to be a limitation on the number of characters that can be in one 'tags' cell (255). Perhaps you need vba after all.

Probably there is an easier way with Excel365 but at least in older versions this works:

Formula in column C:
=INDEX($E$2:$E$9;SUMPRODUCT(--(IFERROR(SEARCH("|"&A2&"|";"|"&$F$2:$F$9&"|");0)>0)*ROW($F$2:$F$9))-1)

For this to work, you need to entry the formula as an array formula pressing CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

If you have Microsoft 365, you could try this (not competing for short answer here :)

for each process id
 MAP(process_ids, LAMBDA(process_id
in tags for order ids, for tags for each order id
MAP(tags_for_order_ids, LAMBDA(tags_for_order_id,
split the tags and look for matches
OR(process_id = TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(tags_for_order_id, "|"))
`
return order id if matched removing non-matches (#NA) with TOCOL
Enter the following in the first cell (C2 in the example), no need to fill-down

=LET(
    process_ids, TRIM(A2:A9),
    tags_for_order_ids, OrderTab!B2:B9,
    order_ids, OrderTab!A2:A9,
    MAP(
        process_ids,
        LAMBDA(process_id,
            IFERROR(
                TOCOL(
                    IF(
                        MAP(
                            tags_for_order_ids,
                            LAMBDA(tags_for_order_id,
                                OR(
                                    process_id =
                                        TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(tags_for_order_id, "|"))
                                )
                            )
                        ),
                        order_ids,
                        NA()
                    ),
                    3
                ),
                "no match"
            )
        )
    )
)



Start a new line of text inside a cell in Excel - Microsoft Support
